# Read of text file never being released from memory

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.6.2

I'm using .NET Framework 4.6.2 (VB) for a Windows Service. I'm using NLog to write a log file without issue. I'm now adding a log viewer utility which will show the last 100 lines of the log file. I've used various methods to read the file but can't seem to escape the reality that I eventually need to iterate through the entire file to get to the lines that I need. That's not a problem.

Where I'm having an issue is that after I've finished reading the file it NEVER seems to get released from memory. When I start my application, it's using approximately 16MB of memory. After the read (of an at most 10MB file) it's using around 38.5MB. Even doing things like clearing the `List(Of String)` or a forced Garbage Collection is never fully releasing the memory.

I'm using probably the simplest version of a read:

```
Dim LogEntries As List(Of String) = System.IO.File.ReadLines(LogFile).ToList()
LogEntries.Clear()
```

I am performing other tasks between the `ReadLines` and `LogEntries.Clear()` steps, but the issue is present even if I use only the lines shown above.

I would expect that on clearing the LogEntries list would return the memory usage to approximately 16MB, but the lowest I've been able to get it (after a `GC.Collect()`) is about 22MB. Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Minor addendum - I just let my application sit for around 40 minutes and the memory was eventually released. I guess my question now becomes, what options to I have to release it immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of calling `ReadLines` is that it doesn't read every line at the same time.  If you then call `ToList` on the result then you force it to wait until all lines are read.  That's silly.  If you want the last 100 lines then you have no choice but to read the whole lot but there's no point keeping it all.

```
Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath)

lines = lines.Skip(lines.Length - 100).ToArray()
```

The first line reads the entire file into a `String` array and then the second line creates a second array containing just the last 100 elements and discards the first array.

Another option that would reduce memory consumption at the expense of performance would be this:

```
Dim lines As New List(Of String)

Using reader As New StreamReader(filePath)
    Do Until reader.EndOfStream
        lines.Add(reader.ReadLine())

        If lines.Count > 100 Then
            lines.RemoveAt(0)
        End If
    Loop
End Using
```

Comment: Appreciate your feedback - and it is an education for me on reading files - but having just tested it seems to suffer the same fate as the method I was using in relation to the memory hogging. The nature of the issue I have isn't with performance of the read, it's with the memory usage of my application being more than doubled after reading a file,

Comment: After your edit, I've experimented a little with the StreamReader approach and discovered that the memory issue isn't actually to do with the read of the text file, but with the `List (Of String)`. I've adapted the approach you've recommended to find a solution.